# Mysql Master-slave Replication

Tags: mysql

i have a master-slave replication which syncs the data with 0 sec delay. But recently i have observed that MySQL master has reached to "too many connections " , so i checked processlist in MySQL master and one of our person addressed the sql injection has attacked , so we killed those queries but unfortunately we lost slave syncing from master.

when i checked for the slaves processlist .., i saw 
mysql> show slave status \G

```
   Last_Errno: 1053
   Last_Error: Query partially completed on the master (error on master: 1053) and was aborted. There is a chance that your master is inconsistent at this point. If you are sure that your master is ok, run this query manually on the slave and then restart the slave with SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1; START SLAVE; . Query: 'update Tracking set outTime = NOW() where id = 'IF(SUBSTR(@@version,1,1)<5,BENCHMARK(2600000,SHA1(0xDEADBEEF)),SLEEP(5))/*'XOR(IF(SUBSTR(@@version,1,1)<5,BENCHMARK(2600000,SHA1(0xDEADBEEF)),SLEEP(5)))OR'|"XOR(IF(SUBSTR(@@version,1,1)<5,BENCHMARK(2600000,SHA1(0xDEADBEEF)),SLEEP(5)))OR"*/''
```

Please somebody help .., how can i resolve this .

Comment: is your DB myISAM or innoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody is running a blind SQL injection attack against your server. This can also act like a denial of service, because the technique relies on creating delays to determine some piece of data in the database.

Edit:

Actually, it's intended to be a denial of service attack. More info: http://0mghax.blogspot.nl/2010/09/mysql-query-timeout-remote-denial-of.html